Global parameters does not appear in the ARMTemplateParametersForFactory.json
I can't figure out how to override global params in my CI/CD pipeline for ADF.
I've added TEST_PARAMETER and when I deploy my adf with below task:
- task: AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment@3
retryCountOnTaskFailure: ${{ parameters.arm_template_deployment_retry_count }}
continueOnError: false
inputs:
  deploymentScope: 'Resource Group'
  azureResourceManagerConnection: ${{ parameters.deployment_service_connection }}
  subscriptionId: $(global.subscription.id)
  action: 'Create Or Update Resource Group'
  resourceGroupName: $(global.resourceGroup.name)
  location: $(global.location.primary)
  templateLocation: 'Linked artifact'
  csmFile: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/adf/ARMTemplateForFactory.json'
  csmParametersFile: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/adf/ARMTemplateParametersForFactory.json'
  overrideParameters: >
    -dataFactory_properties_globalParameters_TEST_PARAMETER_value "111"

I get the following errors:
There was an error while overriding 'dataFactory_properties_globalParameters_TEST_PARAMETER_value' parameter because of 'TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'type')', make sure it follows JavaScript Object Notation (JSON)

Starting template validation.
Deployment name is ARMTemplateForFactory-20240708-211103-e1c1
There were errors in your deployment. Error code: InvalidTemplate.
##[error]Deployment template validation failed: 'The following parameters were supplied, but do not correspond to any parameters defined in the template: 'dataFactory_properties_globalParameters_TEST_PARAMETER_value'. The parameters defined in the template are: 'factoryName, ...

but my parameter is not in the "parameters defined in the template"...
I've enabled Include global parameters in ARM template as suggested by Microsoft on Arm Template ADF screen.
I can see that global params are visible in ARMTemplateForFactory.json but... I still can't override them as they don't exist in ARMTemplateParametersForFactory.json.
I can see that in the root folder of my adf I have file arm-template-parameters-definition.json and beginnign of this files looks like below
{
    "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories": {
        "properties": {
            "globalParameters": {
                "*": {
                    "value": "="
                }
            }
        },
        "location": "="
    },

I've also did an export from my ADF and below files had those global params included:
ARMTemplateForFactory.json
MyADF_ARMTemplateForFactory.json
MyADF_ARMTemplateParametersForFactory.json

In ARMTTemplateForFactory.json, I can see global param defined:
...
        },
        {
            "name": "[concat(parameters('factoryName'), '/default')]",
            "type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/globalparameters",
            "apiVersion": "2018-06-01",
            "properties": {
                "TEST_PARAMETER": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "value": "\"123\""
                }
...

but tbh, I've expected to see it under parameters and not resources. Why it is being defined as resource instead parameter?
I can see my test global param defined as:
"dataFactory_properties_globalParameters_TEST_PARAMETER_value": {
"type": "string",
"defaultValue": ""123""
},
but below file was still missing those global params:
ARMTemplateParametersForFactory.json

Publish_config.json also seems to reflect that global params should be included:
{"publishBranch":"my-publish-branch","includeGlobalParamsTemplate":true}

I feel lost as I'm not sure what I'm missing here... Is it ``arm-template-parameters-definition.json` configuration or maybe something else?

Update
Based on the further discussions, when adding new ADF global parameters then pushing the changes to GIT publish branch, the parameters node in the template file ARMTemplateForFactory.json will not be populated, which incurred the error during ARM deployment.
I could reproduce the issue if the arm-template-parameters-definition.json in ADF studio lacked the block below.

,
    "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/globalparameters": {
        "properties": {
            "globalParameters": {
                "*": {
                    "value": "="
                }
            }
        }
    }

Adding those lines by navigating to ADF studio -> Manage -> ARM Template -> Edit parameter configuration and click on Edit can fix the issue.

Before publishing the templates to GIT Repos, we can Export and download the ARM template file to double check if the required parameters/resources are populated.

This was the expected error when you were trying to override an ARM template parameter value, but the parameter was not claimed in the parameters node in the ARM template file.
Since the ARM template file ARMTemplateForFactory.json and the parameters file ARMTemplateParametersForFactory.json should be updated by the operations in the ADF studio, here are the steps for your reference to make sure the Test_Global_Parameter is defined first, and then it can be overridden during ARM deployment.

To Include global parameters in ARM template and then Publish the change to the ARM template file in the adf_publish branch, will only add the modification in the resources node of the ARM template file but NOT populate any update in the parameters node;


We can add a new Test_Global_Parameter and then Publish the change again to make sure the parameters node in the ARMTemplateForFactory.json file is updated and the ARMTemplateParametersForFactory.json file is also synchronized with a default value for Test_Global_Parameter;




Then you may proceed to test the ARM deployment with the latest version of this ARM template and to override the Test_Global_Parameter value via a pipeline workflow;
parameters:
- name: arm_template_deployment_retry_count
  type: number
  default: 1

- name: deployment_service_connection
  default: ARMSvcCnnSub0

- name: source_adf
  default: azdatafactory-instance0
  values:
  - azdatafactory-instance0
  - azdatafactory-instance1

variables:
  global.subscription.id: $(sub0)
  global.resourceGroup.name: rg-azdatafactory-instance0
  global.location.primary: southeastasia
  adf: ${{ parameters.source_adf }}

trigger:
- adf_publish

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- task: AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment@3
  retryCountOnTaskFailure: ${{ parameters.arm_template_deployment_retry_count }}
  continueOnError: false
  inputs:
    deploymentScope: 'Resource Group'
    azureResourceManagerConnection: ${{ parameters.deployment_service_connection }}
    subscriptionId: $(global.subscription.id)
    action: 'Create Or Update Resource Group'
    resourceGroupName: $(global.resourceGroup.name)
    location: $(global.location.primary)
    templateLocation: 'Linked artifact'
    csmFile: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/$(adf)/ARMTemplateForFactory.json'
    csmParametersFile: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/$(adf)/ARMTemplateParametersForFactory.json'
    overrideParameters: >
      -default_properties_Test_Global_Parameter_value "111"
    # -factoryName "azdatafactory-newinstance"





Hmm ok, I will try that, but does this scenarion is valid when using ADF npm package? I thought that in this scenario, clicking "Publish" is not really needed.

We need to "publish" so that it can populate that new parameter into the ARM template. Per your issue in this post, it only involves the ARM template file and parameter file in the adf_publish branch. you may explore more on ARM deployment to understand the issue better. Hope the answer helps resolve this issue.

Soo I think there is still na issue here and this is troubling me.
I've checked on "include global params in arm template" and hit publish. Then I've added new global parameter and hit publish again. All my global params are still missing in ARMTemplateParametersForFactory.json...
New param is visible in test_global_params_GlobalParameters.json in my publish branch and it is also visible in ARMTemplateForFactory.json but still under resources....
What is going wrong here?

Can you double check if your ADF resource is integrated with the same GIT repo as that of your YAML pipeline? Is the change pushed to any other GIT repo or branch?

I've added another test paramater and git publish again and all files in my publish branch were updated except of ARMTemplateParametersForFactory.json. Why?Is it possible that somehow arm-template-parameters-definition.json affect this?

So the Test_Glabal_Parameter was added into the parameters node in the ARMTemplateForFactory.json file?

ARMTemplateParametersForFactory.json file only contains the default values from the source ADF resource. Even the Test_Glabal_Parameter was not added in that ARMTemplateParametersForFactory.json file, its value is able to be overridden during ARM deployment.

Does the error in this post still exist?

THis is the problem, it is still added under resources and not parameters... Why is that? Is ti because of my parameter configuration?
I can see below line is there:
{
"Microsoft.DataFactory/factories": {
"properties": {
"globalParameters": {
"*": {
"value": "="
}
}
},
"location": "="
},
in the  arm-template-parameters-definition.json.

I don't even have that arm-template-parameters-definition.json file in my adf_publish branch.

This is not in publish branch, it is available in ADF Studio.
So the current problem seems to be the fact that global params are still defined under resources instead of parameters in ARMTemplateForFactory.json, even when I added second param and hit publish again.

What do you mean this is not in publish branch? When you click on Publish button the change should be updated in the template and parameters file in publish branch, be default adf_publish.

Or say, you don't want to use the templates in the publish branch to deploy ADF resource?

Can you double check if the ARM tempate and parameters files in your ADF publish branch (adf_publish branch by default) are updated?

Yes, when I hit Pubslih adf_publish branch is updated but the problem is, global params are still added under resources in json and not under parameters...

I can't reproduce this behavior. What if you test with a new ADF instance integrated with a new GIT repo?

Please also try and navigate to ADF studio -> Mange -> ARM Template -> Edit parameter configuration and click on the Edit -> Check if there are lines:     "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/globalparameters": {
"properties": {
"*": {
"value": "="
}
}
}

Hmm For me, the line looks a bit different....
{
"Microsoft.DataFactory/factories": {
"properties": {
"globalParameters": {
"*": {
"value": "="
}
}
},
"location": "="
},

ok, so after I've added
"Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/globalparameters": {
"properties": {
"*": {
"value": "="
}
}
}
global params started showing as they should....
I thought that "include global parameters in the ARM Template should ad this automatically somehow...

I can only reproduce the issue if without those lines.

Ok, ok, so after I've added "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/globalparameters": { "properties": { "*": { "value": "=" } } } global params started showing as they should.... I thought that "include global parameters in the ARM Template should ad this automatically somehow...

Not sure why your arm-template-parameters-definition.json in ADF studio lacked that Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/globalparameters block, but adding those lines did fix the issue, right?
